# Find locked accounts in Active Directory using PowerShell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -SearchBase "OU=CompanySite,DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com" -SearchScope Subtree | Select SamAccountName

foreach($user in $users)
{
    Write-Host $user.SamAccountName.ToLower()
}
```

I know that there is a locked account in the OU called "CompanySite", but when I execute this code, I don't get any results.

Comment: Try to target the DC holding the PDC Emulator FSMO role: `Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -Server pdc1.example.domain.com`

Comment: Sorry how do I do that?

Comment: You take my sample command above, add your `-SearchBase` parameter, and then replace `pdc1.example.domain.com` with the hostname of the Domain Controller that holds the PDC Emulator FSMO role in the `example.domain.com` domain

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen why the suggestion to use the PDC?